# Google Chrome - download attribute of anchor tags

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download, anchor

I've an extension which saves some files to the downloads folder. The code below is just for testing

```
//This lies in the background page of my extension
function fileTest(name) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = 'data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh'; //Hello World!
    a.download = name + '.txt';
    a.onclick = function (e) {console.log('[TEST] ' + name);return true;};
    a.click();
}
window.onload = function() {
    fileTest('test1');
    fileTest('test12');
    fileTest('test123');
}
```

only the first file "test1.txt" is saved to the disk, although the output of the console shows that there was 3 clicks

> [TEST] test1
>
> [TEST] test12
>
> [TEST] test123

Is this an intentional limitation by the browser ? or there's something wrong with the code ?

Comment: I doubt you couldn't have downloaded single file? including `"test1.txt"`??

Comment: I'm not following up what you mean, the first file is **downloaded** to the disk as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/76LWD/) in a regular browsing session, I get a slide out notification (at the top of the window) that says

> This site is attempting to download multiple files. Do you want to allow this?

So, yes, it is a security limitation of the browser to restrict downloads that are not user-initiated. You probably don't see the notification because the action is being performed by your background page.

The limitation seems to be one download per user action as demonstrated in [this variant](http://jsfiddle.net/5h6uJ/3/) of your code:

```
window.onclick = function() {
    fileTest('test1');
}
```

This will allow unlimited downloads, but only one download per click event.